# How to validate it must be an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it necessary two use two conditions to check if `data` is an object otherwise throw an error?

```
if (typeof data !== "object" || Array.isArray(data)) {
    throw new Error(`data is not an object`);
}
```

It appear `typeof data !== "object"` treated as array as well.

Comment: Arrays are objects. If you want a plain object but not an array, then your condition is correct. Although it will fail for `data = null` because `typeof null === "object"`

Comment: Array is both an `instanceOf` an object and an array. Can `data` ever not be an array? Can it be a number or undefined?

Comment: "Arrays are objects"  and then "If you want a plain object but not an array" - that is confusing but I understood what you mean.

Comment: Plain object - `{key: "value"}`, an array - `[1, 2, 3]`. Your condition checks if the input is the former but not the latter. So, it checks if it's a plain object not an array.

Comment: @Dom Yes, `data` can not ever be an array. I don't know why it's still an instanceOf 
 object. Misleading right?

Comment: Because *array* is a type of object. The inheritance goes `Object` -> `Array`. So all arrays *are* objects, not all objects are arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to a regular object, both `null` and `Array` will also have typeof as "object" so if you're trying to make sure it's only a regular object and not `null` or `Array`, then you would just add one more check to what you already had:

```
if (!data || typeof data !== "object" || Array.isArray(data)) {
    throw new Error(`data is not an object`);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve expected result, use below option of verifying whether data is object or array by constructor name

In Javascript, there is no separate data type for array and they are list-like objects

As per MDN- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

> The JavaScript Array object is a global object that is used in the
>   construction of arrays; which are high-level, list-like objects.

Refer this link for more details - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

```js
var data1 = [1,2,3]
var data2= {
a:1,
b:2
}

var data3= Object.create(null)
var data4= null;

console.log("data1-type", data1.constructor && data1.constructor.name || typeof data1)
console.log("data2-type", data2.constructor && data2.constructor.name || typeof data2)
console.log("data3-type", data3.constructor && data3.constructor.name || typeof data3)
console.log("data4-type", data4 && data4.constructor && data4.constructor.name || typeof data4)
```

Comment: This is not a foolproof methods - `Object.create(null)` will create a plain object but it will not have a `constructor` property. Also. it still fails if the variable is simply `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @VLAZ, to support both scenarios, adding typeof will provide valid output..updated my answer

Comment: I don't know why you're going to such great lengths to avoid `Array.isArray()`.

Comment: @jfriend00, with Array.isArray is one of the option to check whether variable is array or not and it will not help to check whether null is is object or not and for function as well.. for only array verification Array.isArray is the best option